# Cannot find snapshot for id: gradle

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm getting error of cannot find snapshot for id while building the project.

on running the command `./gradlew build --info` I received the information saying that PROJECT_FOLDER/build/libs/projectName.jar has been removed.

I tried to look for the same, but its generating the jar at said location.

It was running fine till yesterday all of a sudden started facing this issue.

Now, I have no clue how should I go ahead finding the root cause.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

I'm using gradle 4.2.1 for building the project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try to remove .gradle directory from your project and build your gradle again

Comment: Ok Iet me check

Comment: it's seems because you upgrade the latest gradle version and .gradle store cache of old and new both version cache. Sometime it's not work properly that's why we need to remove .gradle directory to avoid this issue.... :)